# Extract tweets for a specific time span, using SearchTwitter

Tags: r, twitter

Is there another method to extract tweets for a specific time span, rather than using number of tweets, using SearchTwitter? I am able to fetch a certain number of tweets for Nordstrom but have not been successful is doing so for specific dates.

```
library('twitteR')

nord1<- searchTwitteR("#nordstrom", n= 1000) #works fine

nord2<- searchTwitteR('nordstrom', since = '2012-01-01', until = '2015-11-13')
```

> **Warning message:
>   In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
>     25 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0**

Comment: you need to format your question.

Comment: I think you're [out of luck](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) `The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.`

Comment: Thanks @rawr for reformatting & responding to my question, I`m still new to this. It seems like you`re right! I was able to extract tweets earliest 2015-11-20 until 2015-11-27.

Comment: @mbench welcome to so.. you can answer your own question and mark it accepted if it addresses your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter search API only allows access to the most recent tweets (last 6-9 days). I was instead searching for much earlier dates when I came across the issue.